# Ember JS super basic routing, using just static templates

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-router

I have been trying to wrap my head around how Ember routing works on a very basic level and need a little kick in the right direction.  I am providing the code I have written so far, hopefully you can follow along and see what is going on

I would like to see a **page hierarchy** like so:

```
index
--Red
----Light
----Medium
----Dark
--Green
----Light
----Medium
----Dark
--Blue
----Light
----Medium
----Dark
```

The "medium" colors are actually going to be the index for each nested route, So I think I need `router.js` set up like so:

```
Colors.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('red', { path: '/red' }, function(){
      this.route('light-red');
      this.route('dark-red');
    });
    this.resource('green', { path: '/green'}, function(){
      this.route('light-green');
      this.route('dark-green');
     });
    this.resource('blue', { path: '/blue'}, function(){
      this.route('light-blue');
      this.route('dark-blue');
    });
   });
```

For now, I just want to serve up static html templates (with just a little bit of `#link-to` handlebars for navigation)... just so I can see a working prototype.

**The main template** is here

```
<div id="emberColors">
    <header id="mainHeader">
      <h1>Ember Colors</h1>
      <p>Pick a color</p>
      <nav class="navi main">
        <ul>
          <li>{{#link-to "red" activeClass="active"}}Red{{/link-to}}</li>
          <li>{{#link-to "blue" activeClass="active"}}Blue{{/link-to}}</li>
          <li>{{#link-to "green" activeClass="active"}}Green{{/link-to}}</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

{{outlet}}

<footer id="footer">
  <p>Ok Buh-bye</p>
</footer>
```

I have a **template for each of the three colors**, each is set up like this:

```
<section id="blue">
  <header>
    <h1>The Blue</h1>
    <p>Blue is cool.</p>
    <nav class="navi sub">
      <ul>
        <li>{{#link-to "blue.light-blue"}}Light{{/link-to}}</li>
        <li>{{#link-to "blue"}}Base{{/link-to}}</li>
        <li>{{#link-to "blue.dark-blue}}Dark{{/link-to}}</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  {{outlet}}

</section>
```

And I broke up **each "shade" into multiple templates**

```
<div class="color-lt">
  <p>Light Blue</p>
</div>
```

*Note:  I also understand that I can reuse templates and load different model data into them, rather than hard coding lots of little templates... but I am just trying to focus on learning the routing at the moment.*

Because these are just basic templates, I assume (based on what I have read) Ember auto-generates a lot of the MVC and I don't need to define any specific controllers, models, or routes (except for perhaps the IndexRoutes for the three main color landing pages).

I understand that the naming convention for the templates will help ember do most of the work.

However it is the naming conventions that are confusing me.

in `router.js` it seems simple enough to define the routes by how I want it to appear in the URL

in handlebars `{{#link-to}}` though, it looks like I need to reference the URL (or template?) name with a `.` separation (include dashes or no)?

and when defining an index route it is structured with PascalCase?

I need some help with figuring out how to properly name/declare these routes so that Ember can render them correctly.

for instance: because of the nested nature of these pages... do I need to store my templates in a nested directory file structure as well?  or is that being done artificially by ember routing?

Is there a general MVC Routing methodology that I am supposed to understand before I can understand Ember Routing specifically?

Sorry, I have a lot of questions about this... It seems like it is supposed to be really simple, but I don't know why I am not getting it.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**  I will also let you know that, as I have it written out currently, Ember Inspector is not throwing any errors that I can see.  So I am convinced, that so far I am on the right track, but I am just not providing anything for the router to resolve...

Comment: I recommend you to begin using ember-cli, it solves most of the ember convention setup to start easily with your ember app.

Comment: Oh, I was under the impression that ember-cli was still in development and not quite ready for production?

Comment: Talk with people at the irc at #emberjs. I do not use for my project, but I know people who have already adopted in their projects. It will definitely  solve most of the issues regarding your project structure and build tools.

Comment: so how can you suggest for me to use something that will solve my problems, if you yourself do not use it?

Comment: The build setup of my project is complex, it is based in a broccoli setup which precompiles templates in the server side. One similar demo example is available at: https://github.com/ppcano/ember-app. Many of my build setup configuration is inspired on ember-cli. Depending on your confortable level, you could do it by yourself or using a tool as ember-cli. Based on your question, I recommended you ember-cli, perhaps I am wrong.